# How can I tell the reason for a call disconnect in android

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

Im writing an android app which has a dialler component. I am able to determine when the call has ended with a PhoneStateListener but I need to also know the cause of the disconnect eg busy, no answer etc

How can this be done?